# how to add only double values in jformattedtextfield

Tags: java, swing, jformattedtextfield

I need to format jformattedtextfeild for only add double/float values with two decimal places in runtime. 

**ex: 15600.00**

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html). Remember, `JFormattedTextField` is post validate, that it's it doesn't do real time validation of the input

Comment: Consider using a `JSpinner` with `SpinnerNumberModel` instead of `JFormattedTextField`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example on how to do it:

```
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance();
format.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
format.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
format.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
JFormattedTextField myTwoDecimalTextfield = new JFormattedTextField(format);
myTwoDecimalTextfield.setValue(new Float(3.14));
```